# Kotlin Spinner OnItemSelected Intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

Hey guys I created a spinner with three options. Now I want the user to decide for one option. Then the user should be directed to the fitting activity. But I get an error by adding an Intent method to the on Item selected. So it "Doesn't know" the function type

```
option.onItemSelectedListener = object: AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                result.text = options.get(p2)
                if (options.get(p2) == "3 Rounds") {
                    val intent = Intent(this, Settings::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
                result.text = "Please Select"
            }
        }
```

When I press Alt + Enter it just says to create a function.

Comment: `val intent = Intent(this@YourActivity, Settings::class.java)` try this

Comment: Also, check the answer and accept it.  Because it's also helpful to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin you have to mention your Activity name after `this` keyword followed with`@`

`val intent = Intent(this@YourActivity, Settings::class.java)`